# Write a program that return the first 3 numbers greater than 11 in array and then return as many as you find?

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program that return the first 3 numbers greater than 11. If there are fewer than 3 numbers greater than 11, then return as many as you find. You will always return an array size 3.
Zeroes will fill the array if there are not 3 numbers greater than 11.
How i solve this question.
This is how i started my code:

```
public class RayGetNums
{
    //method go will return an array
    //containing the first 3 numbers
    //greater than 11
    public static int[] go(int[] ray)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Runner that i use with this question is this:

```
class Runner
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    RayGetNums rt = new RayGetNums();

        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{-99,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12345} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,-99} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,-11818,40,30,20,10} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{32767} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{255,255} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{9,10,-88,100,-555,1000} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{10,10,10,11,456} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{-111,1,2,3,9,11,20,30} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,-2,-989} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{12,15,18,21,23,1000} ) );
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{250,19,17,15,13,11,10,9,6,3,2,1,-455} ) ); 
        System.out.println( rt.go( new int[]{9,10,-8,10000,-5000,1000} ) );
  }
}
```

The answers that i need we this runner:

```
[12345, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[20, 30, 40]
[32767, 0, 0]
[255, 255, 0]
[100, 1000, 0]
[456, 0, 0]
[20, 30, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[12, 15, 18]
[250, 19, 17]
[10000, 1000, 0]
```

Thank you

Comment: You're off to a reasonable start.  What is the main issue preventing you from progressing further?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to add elements greater than 11 to an array and return it.

```
public static int[] go(int[] ray)
{
    int[] res = new int[]{0,0,0};
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ray.length && count < 3; i++) {
        if ( ray[i] > 11 ) {
            res[count++] = ray[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```